# What's the difference between Jackdaw and KillerBee on RZ Raven USB Stick

Tags: smart-home, security, zigbee

What is the difference between Jackdaw and KillerBee on ZigBee USB Stick, both seem to be sniffing packet, but Jackdaw can act as a network interface, and KillerBee is only used for pentest? As far as I understand it, you can't use either to connect to like a hub or Wireless router, but only to ZigBee based devices, which would be the IoT devices such as sensors or smart socket etc.

Comment: Hi Terry, I assume you are referring to these things [(Jackdaw)](http://contiki.sourceforge.net/docs/2.6/a01799.html) and [KillerBee](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjb7PGwgc3UAhXHL8AKHbNeArYQFghAMAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftools.kali.org%2Fwireless-attacks%2Fkillerbee&usg=AFQjCNHRnxXaKP_UdmW25POrBFbKHOqA5A)?

Comment: Yes, that's the things I'm referring to :)